# Are CFLs available with mini candelabra bases?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bulb

Trying to replace a light bulb that has a **mini** candelabra base and want to replace this bulb with a CFL bulb but can't find any. Are CFLs available with **mini** candelabra bases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you know what you want, an E-11 base CFL, not the more common E-12 sized base candelabra that Mr. Sherman linked to. Unfortunately, the mini term gets thrown around alot, referring to the over all size, not the base size. As you have found, E-11 CFLs are pretty rare, if they exist at all. However, you can get adapters that fit in E-11 sockets and accept E-12 based CFLs. Obviously they extend the height of the final installation, and some E-12 CFLs are fairly huge in the first place. However, if you look around, you can find E-12 CFLs that are reasonably sized, and even have something similar to the traditional candelabra shape. Happy searching :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Sylvania Micro-Mini candelabra base](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007H9O4VS) to fit fine. The fluorescent corkscrew was also small enough to fit under my paddle fan's diffuser, unlike a couple other brands I tried. I found them at my local Lowes, picked them up with a few other options, tried them all out, and returned the ones that didn't fit.

If these don't fit, it's possible you're out of luck.